# Continuous clicking on ion-icon not working on IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Continuous clicking on ion-icon does call decrementQty() method multiple times on IOS while it is working on Android.

```
<ion-icon qty-icons  name="remove" (click)="decrementQty()">
```

Problem: If I click multiple times on the icon-icon, decrementQty() does not get called.

Expected:  decrementQty() should be called multiple times with click events as on Android.

how can I achieve the same on IOS?

Comment: Does it not work at all on iOS, or does it get called sometimes? Can you try to add the `(click)` event on the parent element, for example the button?

Comment: I'm using span as button, added some padding and background color to this. if I single click on the ion-icon then it is working but if I do multiple in a short duration then it is not working.

Comment: have you tried `(tap)` instead of click?

Comment: I'm trying wrapping ion-icon to ion-button, might resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible issues:

1. If you add the click handler directly to the ion-icon element, the hitbox could be only the actual icon itself, which makes it hard to click. The easiest way to solve this would be to wrap it in a button.
2. IOS has a click delay of 300ms on every element except a few (`<a>` and `<button>` elements, maybe more). Ionic provides a directive called `tappable` to remove this delay. `<ion-icon tappable qty-icons  name="remove" (click)="decrementQty()">`

All in all my suggestion would be to wrap the icon in a button and add the click handler there.